# Extract dark contour

Tags: opencv

I want to extract the darker contours from images with opencv. I have tried using a simple threshold such as below (c++)

```
cv::threshold(gray, output, threshold, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

I can iterate threshold lets say from  50 ~ 200
then I can get the darker contours in the middle
for images with a clear distinction such as this

[image: clear]

here is the result of the threshold

[image: threshold]

but if the contours near the border, the threshold will fail because the pixel almost the same.
for example like this image.

[image: not clear]

What i want to ask is there any technique in opencv that can extract darker contour in the middle of image even though the contour reach the border and having almost the same pixel as the border?

(updated)

after threshold darker contour in the middle overlapped with border top.
It makes me fail to extract character such as the first two "SS".

[image]

Comment: Can you add an expected result? The way your question is formulated, I don't get what you mean by _extract darker contour in the middle of the image_

Comment: Even add the result you are getting by the last image then it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Try adaptiveThreshold

Comment: @RickM. so from the last image, the darker contour in the middle should be "SS400-17 291330-04'. I tried using the threshold technique but the pixel overlapped with border edge.

Comment: @Miki I tried your suggestion but the result has too many noises. The first two characters "SS" using noise removal most likely can be extracted but the other characters become difficult. see [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVmd5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply add a edge preserving smoothing step to solve this :

```
// read input image
Mat inputImg = imread("test2.tif", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

Mat filteredImg;
bilateralFilter(inputImg, filteredImg, 5, 60, 20);

// compute laplacian
Mat laplaceImg;
Laplacian(filteredImg, laplaceImg, CV_16S, 1);

// threshold
Mat resImg;
threshold(laplaceImg, resImg, 10, 1, THRESH_BINARY);

// write result
imwrite("res2.tif", resImg);
```

This will give you the following result : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tbfW.jpg)

Regards,

Comment: thank you again. I accepted your answer. BilateralFilter and Laplacian are the key to solve this issue. Now I need to find the correct parameters of bilateralFilter and threshold automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think using laplacian could partialy solve your problem :

```
// read input image
Mat inputImg = imread("test2.tif", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

// compute laplacian
Mat laplaceImg;
Laplacian(inputImg, laplaceImg, CV_16S, 1);

Mat resImg;
threshold(laplaceImg, resImg, 30, 1, THRESH_BINARY);

// write result
imwrite("res2.tif", resImg);
```

Using this code you should obtain something like :
[this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDYiw.jpg)

You can then play with final threshold value and with laplacian kernel size.

You will probably have to remove small artifacts after this operation.

Regards

Comment: thank you for the reply. I saw your result but the two characters "SS" is cut off to half after apply noise removal.